# Additional IP-Address overwrites old one?

Tags: networking, server, 22.04, netplan, ip

My hosting provider gave me an additional ip-address and now i am trying to add it to my netplan but somehow it is overwriting the main-ip. Here is my netplan:

```
### Hetzner Online GmbH installimage
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp35s0:
      match:
        macaddress: 00:50:56:00:F9:3B
      addresses:
        - 167.235.117.189/32
        - 167.235.117.188/24
        - 2a01:4f8:2200:21cd::2/64
      routes:
        - on-link: true
          to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 167.235.117.129
        - to: default
          via: fe80::1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 185.12.64.1
          - 2a01:4ff:ff00::add:2
          - 185.12.64.2
          - 2a01:4ff:ff00::add:1
```

the ip ending with .189 is my main ip the other one ending with 188 is my secondary ip. The macaddress "belongs" to the ip ending with .188 .
Can somebody help me? Thank u so much!

Edit:
After doing what @Terrance told me my new config looks like this:

```
### Hetzner Online GmbH installimage
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp35s0:
      match:
        macaddress: 00:50:56:00:F9:3B
      addresses:
        - 167.235.117.189/32:
             label: "enp35s0:0"
          
        - 167.235.117.188/32:
             label: "enp35s0:1"

        - 2a01:4f8:2200:21cd::2/64
      routes:
        - on-link: true
          to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 167.235.117.129
        - to: default
          via: fe80::1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 185.12.64.1
          - 2a01:4ff:ff00::add:2
          - 185.12.64.2
          - 2a01:4ff:ff00::add:1
```

Comment: You need to assign each IP to a virtual interface.  See https://netplan.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/#how-to-use-multiple-addresses-on-a-single-interface  Also, with the next example below the one pointed to in the document, you are able to assign without the virtual as long as the IP addresses are not in the same subnet.  As it stands, your IP addresses that they gave to you are in the same subnet.

Comment: @Terrance I updated my post. Issue still persists

Comment: Unless you have a second interface of `enp35s1`, that probably won't work.  In the documentation it states to use the `label:`.  In your case it should be like `label: "enp35s0:0"` below the first address, then `label: "enp35s0:1"` below the second address.  The system needs a way to keep the IPs separated.

Comment: Ok. I did this @Terrance . But somehow i still have the same issue..

Comment: Have you rebooted after the update? There should be no issues in having multiple addresses on one interface (and the labels aren't necessary), but in my experience `netplan apply` isn't always successful in making a 'delta' change on a running system, whereas after the reboot everything comes up as intended. (I assume your provider offers console access to the system - for the unlikely event that you break your network config?)

Comment: The documentation explains that you CAN use labels.  You do not HAVE to use labels, and that would have nothing to do with the addresses not being assigned.  Labels are NOT virtual interfaces.

Comment: How have you determined that the new address is "overwriting" the original one?  What is the output of `ip addr show`, and what is the incorrect behavior you're seeing?